# cohomology of a blowup: reference needed

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, blow-ups

Does anybody know a reference in which the computation of the cohomology of a blow-up is made in detail?

Comment: Have you looked into SGA5, section VII?

Comment: Thanks Konrad. Is this available online?

Comment: googling immediately gives you this: http://library.msri.org/books/sga/sga5/index.html

Comment: or SGA7, vol. II, p.258.

Comment: Another alternative: Griffiths and Harris, Chapter 4, Section 6, subsection "Blowing Up Submanifolds."